# Issue Unknown type name NSManagedObject

Tags: core-data, ios5, nsmanagedobject

I'm trying to have a very simple Core Data. I have a ViewController.h like this :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (IBAction)boutonSave:(id)sender;

@end
```

and a ViewController.m like that :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (IBAction)boutonSave:(id)sender {
ViewController *viewController = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [viewController managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *newJournee; //THIS LINE IN ERROR
newJournee = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"JourneeDeTravail" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[newJournee setValue:_displayStart.text forKey:@"debut"];
[newJournee setValue:_displayEnd.text forKey:@"fin"];
```

}

But when creating newJournee, I have a red alert "Unknow type name 'NSManagedObject',  did you mean NSManagedObjectModel ?" ??? It's my first Core Data so I certainly missed something obvious to you... but not to me ! Help !

Comment: sounds like you missed an #import

Comment: Yes, you're right ! Adding #import <CoreData/CoreData.h> at the beginning did fix it ! Thanks !

Answer (score 19):

add CoreData.framework and import like below

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
```

hope it helps~

Answer (score 5):

sounds like you missed an #import

Comment: Yes had a similar problem the import was in - Prefix.pch --> 
//
//  Prefix header
//
//  The contents of this file are implicitly included at the beginning of every source file.
//

#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_5_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 5.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
   #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#endif

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry. Everything seems fine..

Just do one thing..Goto the ViewController.m file of yours and add this line.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (IBAction)boutonSave:(id)sender {
ViewController *viewController = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [viewController managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *newJournee; //Error removed
newJournee = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"JourneeDeTravail" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[newJournee setValue:_displayStart.text forKey:@"debut"];
[newJournee setValue:_displayEnd.text forKey:@"fin"];
```

Hope this helped.